# GestureRecognizer not working on CollectionView with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gesture

I am playing around in Xamarin with GestureRecognizers, and I have the following code:

```cs
<CollectionView
  Grid.Row="0"
  EmptyView="No player information"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Voices, Mode=OneWay}">

  <CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
      Command="{Binding CommandPlayerTapped}"
      CommandParameter="hi"
      NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
  </CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>

  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>

      <StackLayout>
        <views:PancakeItemView Margin="5" BorderColor="Black">
          <views:VoiceInfoContainerView Style="{StaticResource VoiceDisplayStyle}" />
        </views:PancakeItemView>
      </StackLayout>

    </DataTemplate>
  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

My `TapGestureRecognizer` is bound to a simple Command that makes a popup message; nothing complex.
The DataTemplate is a PancakeView wrapping a simple view to show some names like shown here:

[image: Screenshot showing View]

Again, this is nothing complex, however, I feel this may be where the problem lies, as I cannot find any other information online.

I have tried putting the gesture code in other elements, with no success. Any ideas as to why tappingthese views fails to trigger the command?

Comment: Binding error could be an issue (Check for binding errors and if BindingContext is set correctly). Or the parent might already have a TapGestureRecogniser

Comment: Are you trying to add a GestureRecognizer for the item tap of your CollectionView, or a Click in your CollectionView itself?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais One for each item. I have tried putting the gesture in the Data Template, however, yielding the same result.

Comment: there are built in events for handling this, you do not need to add your own gestures.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#single-selection

Comment: Thanks everyone for the information!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CollectionView has a property for the [SelectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#single-pre-selection)

```
SelectionMode="Single"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVoice}"
```

And then on your ViewModel:

```
private Voice _selectedVoice; //I don't know what type of items is your Collection Voices, so i'm using Voice here
public Voice SelectedVoice
{
    get { return _selectedVoice; }
    set { 
          _selectedVoice = value; 
          CommandPlayerTapped.Execute();
        }
}


...

//On the function that CommandPlayerTapped called:

if(SelectedVoice != null)
{
    //Your code
}
else{
    //The Item was deselected
}
```

---

Here is a little extra on the way you were trying previously and why it didn't work:

If you are trying  to set an GestureRecognizer for each item in your CollectionView, you are using it in the wrong place, you are setting the GR in the Collection Itself, not in each item.

You need to pass the correct [BindingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics), your item's have the `Voices` ItemSource BindingContext, but you need the ViewModel Context instead, you can reference a diferent Context (eg: the CollectionView itself),

First make your CollectionView reference by adding x:Name="CollectionViewForBinding" for example:

```
<CollectionView
  x:Name="CollectionViewForBinding"
  Grid.Row="0"
  EmptyView="No player information"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Voices, Mode=OneWay}">
```

And then you reference the BindingContext Like This:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer
              Command="{Binding BindingContext.CommandPlayerTapped, Source={x:Reference Name=CollectionViewForBinding}}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding ThePropertyOfTheItemYouWantToPass}"
              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <views:PancakeItemView Margin="5" BorderColor="Black">
        <views:VoiceInfoContainerView Style="{StaticResource VoiceDisplayStyle}" />
    </views:PancakeItemView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great help. I didn't realise there was a selected item option at all. Also, Should you manually deselect (set to -1) in certain cases? Thanks again!

Comment: On the way i did, in your CommandPlayerTapped function that you are calling, you will have the SelectedVoice, if it's null, it's because it was deselected

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais why is this horrible? it gets around having to implement custom renders on all the platforms to get around the CollectionViews SelectedItem Color. The command is only registered once under the hood with a reference passed to each child item. I believe the CollectionView SelectionChanged command does the same thing under the hood. Could you elaborate on that opinion please.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt maybe i exagerated on the "Horrible" part, what i meant to say is that it was bad for what the user was trying to achieve, the 2º piece of code i wrote is for situations that you already provided, and you can just make a bindable comand property on the object that is being listed, removing the need of an external context, for what the original question asked, there was already a solution and way more simpler to implement, the SeletedItem property already does that and the code is maintained by Xamarin, i removed the unnecessary "horrible" part from the solution